# Change file .htaccess for redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using file `.htaccess`, i would like to redirect from `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/en`, when i get to `http://example.com`

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```